# Retrieving table data through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table in my `changeStatus.jsp` code included below. Now I have to clear all the table data through a jquery function that should be included in the `changeStatus.js` code that follows. Please help with a solution.

changeStatus.jsp:

```
 <table  class="data"   style="width: 100%" id="${ns}changeStatusTable" style="table-layout:fixed; word-wrap: break-word">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th style="width: 10%">Cable</th>
                     <th style="width: 7%">Pair</th>
                     <th  style="width: 25%">Defective Code</th>
                     <th  style="width: *">Remarks</th>
                     <logic:equal name="ChangeStatusBean" property="rowError" value="false">
                         <th  style="width: 30%">Error Message</th>
                     </logic:equal>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody> 
                  <logic:iterate id="rowData" indexId="idx" name="ChangeStatusBean"
                        property="rowData">
                      <tr style="width: 100%">
                        <td style="width: 10%" id=cable" ><html:text value="" styleId="${ns}cable1" property="cable"  maxlength="10" style="width:10em" /></td>
                        <td style="width: 7%" id="pair"><html:text value=""  styleId="${ns}pair1" property="pair" maxlength="4" style="width:7em"/></td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" id="code"><html:select styleId="${ns}defectiveCode"  name="ChangeStatusBean" 
                            property="defectiveCode"  style="width:275px" >
                                 <html:option value="">Select</html:option>
                                 <html:optionsCollection property="defectiveCodeList" label="value" value="value" />
                             </html:select></td>
                        <td style="width: *" id="remarks"><html:text value=""  styleId="${ns}remark" property="remark"  style="width:275px"  maxlength="14"/></td>
                        <logic:equal name="ChangeStatusBean" property="rowError" value="false">
                            <td style="width: 30%" id="errorMessage"><html:text value=""  styleId="${ns}errorMsg" property="errorMessage" style="width:275px" /></td>
                        </logic:equal>
                      </tr>
                  </logic:iterate>               
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

changeStatus.js:

```
ChangeStatusPage.prototype.clearTableData = function(){
    var $table = $(this.hashtag + this.ns + "changeStatusTable");
    var $rows = $table.find('tr').length;
    alert("no of rows: "+$rows/2);
    for(var i=1;i<$rows/2;i++){
         $(this.hashtag + this.ns + "cable"+i).val("");
    }
         return false;
};
```

Comment: `$(table).empty()` If that's not what you want, then you should be more clear on what you are trying to achieve I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply clear all the contents of the table by doing:

```
$('#table_id td').text('');
```

Where  `table_id` above is whatever the actual id is.

If you only want to clear certain cells (which apparently is what you are trying to do) then you can use a more specific selector. For example:

```
$('#table_id td.cable').text('');
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ4MM/2/